# Python unable to import module within library

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyqt5, libraries

I'm trying to use the QSerialPort module of PyQt5. Everything I have found has indicated that QtSerial which contains QSerialPort should come with PyQt5. For example,

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtSerial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtSerial' from 'PyQt5' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py)
```

I've tried installing PyQt5 from inside PyCharm, as well as on the command line with pip. I've tried upgrading pip and reinstalling PyQt5. I'm able to use other modules of PyQt5, for example PyQt5.QtWidgets imports without any problem. I've also tried installing `qt5-serialport-595` and `qt51-serialport` from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org) (I'm using Archlinux), to no avail.

I can see when I go to the command line and run `$ pip list -v PyQt5` that PyQt5 is installed at `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` and when I look there, I can see that the file `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtSerialPort.abi3.so` exists. However I am also not able to import PyQt5.QtSerial as it is also not found, albeit with a slightly different message: `ImportError: libQt5SerialPort.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This is not caused by a typo in the import statement. I've tried pretty much every possible permutation of the letters Q and T and the words Serial and Port. How can I use the serial module of PyQt5?

Comment: Does `from PyQt5 import QtSerialPort` work?

Comment: How did you try and import it? What happened when you tried?

Comment: @James No.
@ JeffUK every way I could think of. `import QtSerial`, `from PyQt5 import QtSerial`, `from PyQt5.QtSerial import QSerialPort` etc. I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'QtSerial' from 'PyQt5'` or `ImportError: libQt5SerialPort.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yeah I think it is QtSerialPort as this is what I see in other people's code: `from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort`. This doesn't work for you?

Comment: @RolvApneseth
     >>> from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: libQt5SerialPort.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you running your scripts from within pycharm? And if so, do you have pyqt5 installed on the pycharm environment for the script you're running. I see your answer below worked for you, just curious

Comment: @RolvApneseth I am using PyCharm for development but I'm testing the import on the command line for now. I have pycharm configured to use the system python for this project; the path in PyCharm is the same as the output of `which python` on the command line.

Comment: If this helps I write it in separate lines, like this:  `from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort`
`from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPortInfo` and suddenly it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this Archlinux forums post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1655833#p1655833) I ran `pacman -Si python-pyqt5` which gave me a list of optional deps that included the line `qt5-serialport: QtSerialPort` so I used yay to install qt5-serialport. This is distinct from [qt51-serialport](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qt51-serialport), [qt5-serialport-595](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qt5-serialport-595/), and in fact any of the [AUR packages with serialport in the name that can be found by searching the AUR site](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&SeB=nd&K=serialport&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go), for some reason. Now when I use python on the command line, I can `from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort` with no error.

I should note that neither the package repo at `https://pypi.python.org/simple` which PyCharm is using to find installable packages, nor the searchable AUR listing, nor pip seems to show qt5-serialport as an option. So even though I got it downloaded and python can find it from the command-line, it still isn't being imported by PyCharm, which is a separate issue.