# PyCharm finds library but not module

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, ide

I am using PyQt5 in PyCharm Community Edition. I have installed qt5-serialport as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985940/python-unable-to-import-module-within-library) and when I use python on the command line I am able to do `from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort` and use the QSerialPort module with no problem in the interactive python environment and when running a python script that makes use of the QSerialPort module, so it's clear that python itself is finding the module just fine. However in PyCharm, the module is not found despite the fact that I'm using the system python as the interpreter. On the line `from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort` PyCharm underlines QSerialPort in red and it doesn't offer any tooltip suggestions for methods etc. on any QSerialPort object I instantiate.

Normally when I get this kind of problem I install the package using the installer within PyCharm but this particular package doesn't seem to be in any public repo listing I can find. (Somehow yay found it, despite it not being listed in the searchable AUR). Other modules in the PyQt5 package import in PyCharm without problems. How can I get PyCharm Community Edition to recognize this module?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall it thru the terminal using `pip install PyQt5`?

Comment: This did it, although I don't understand why. If you write this as an answer with an explanation of how this makes all modules available, while installing PyQt5 inside the IDE only makes some available, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing it on the terminal should work using `pip` from [python.org](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#pip).

```
pip install PyQt5
```

This approach appears to work since it has the core features for finding, downloading, and installing packages from various Python package indexes. More info on [pip from python.org](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#pip).

According to the [Troubleshooting tips from JetBrains](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#pip) listed for PyCharm, there is useful info on debugging import errors using PyQt. So this may be the cause as to why installation through the IDE was not working even though PyQt was installed on the interpreter.